# Convert arrays to values (with keys!) in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I scoured lots of posts for turning arrays into objects and it looks like there are A LOT of posts doing the reverse of what I'd like. If this is redundant with another post I'd like to see what the title is since I really struggled to find it!

I have two arrays:

```
let x = [1,2,3]
let y = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I want to create an array of objects with keys so that the resulting array looks like:

```
data = [
  {x: 1, y: "a"},
  {x: 2, y: "b"},
  {x: 3, y: "c"}
]
```

I tried Object.assign and some other methods but am still struggling (and I'd also like to know what key words I should have used to search if this is already posted since I couldn't find it). Any help appreciated!

Comment: you can do this with a basic for loop

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using map with index

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3];
let y = ["a", "b", "c"];

const res = x.map((el, i) => ({ x: el, y: y[i] }));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple for loop

```
let x = [1,2,3]
let y = ["a", "b", "c"]

let data = [];

for(let i = 0 ; i < x.length; i++){
    data.push({x:x[i],y:y[i]});
}
```